# Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsjTo.jpg)

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="NSoft.FinanceERP.Web.login" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
Line 4:  
Line 5:  <!DOCTYPE html>

Source File: /telerik/login.aspx    Line: 3 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: Make sure Telerik.Web.UI dll is in your bin or it is reference on the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Telerik.Web.UI.dll` reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check that you are referencing the right version of the assembly: it may be referencing a version that is cached.